# jquery queue to parent rather than specific children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, queue, children

I am making some animation on children of a div, the children are animating one at a time on hover, while the other are stopping, and sometimes being removed too. 
What I wanted though is a callback for when all the animation has stopped/ ceased / or is no longer moving - in other words.

...I tried to make something like this, to queue directly to the parent, but this doesn't seem to work at all:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            $(document).ready(function(){   

                $('div.start').click(function(){

                    $('<img style="display:block;display:none;" src="http://www.laserpros.com/images/site/HP_Circle_Logo_Vector1_small.jpg">')
                    .appendTo($(this))
                    .animate({opacity:0},0)
                    .css('display','block')
                    .animate({opacity:1},2000,function(){});

                    $(this).queue(function(){
                        $('#gotcha').html(1+parseInt($('#gotcha').html()));
                    });

                });         
            });
            </script>
        <style>
            div.start{
                background-color:#0057D8;
                width:100px;
                float:left;
            }
            div#gotcha{
                float:left;
                width:100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
        <div class="start">Start</div>
        <div id="gotcha">
            0
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The number was suppossed to change once animation is complete, but this never happens.
Is there any other approach I could do? Or perhaps to get the remaining time of fx somehow, and go with a setTimeout?

Any advice is appreciated.

**EDIT**: Why would I want to do this?

In real I have a range of small thumbs images, and upon hovering them, they create their bigger counterparts in dom which on load attach themselves to a showcase div.
the attached images stack with each other, to achieve a smooth transition effect, the latest image loaded is being animated, while also stopping the other siblings from animating.
upon unhover I want to create a timeout once all the animations stopped to zoom back to the original picture.
I tried to use .children('img:last').queue(function(){}) to queue the zoom back effect to the latest child, however because they are loaded asynchronously with load event their sequence is not clear, moreover once the animation is complete, and if we don't unhover quickly, it takes opacity 1 and removes the other siblings from parent as well. So it's really hard to guess what children shall we bind the queue to.

**EDIT 2**: Right now I modified my code a little bit, and I only attach the img to the div once its loaded, so the last loaded always available with img: last selector, but something tells me that this is not protected from bugs either.

Right now I'm thinking best would be to do something like this:

1. Get isAnimated for all children.
2. If animated - get the duration and set timeout event.
3. If no - execute the event directly.

The problem though is that I have no idea how to get the remaining duration of the animations. It would greatly help if you give some advice on that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing I was trying to do was simply impossible as it seems.

The solution for the problem raised was following:

make step for the child's animation and set time needed to complete it.

Then take this variable, and set timeout, so it would be executed after the animation.

It is also possible that any of the children can write into that variable, so we wouldn't need to search though them.

In the end it perfectly accomplished my task.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've understood the question correctly, but it seems that every time the user clicks on "start", the image should appear and the number gets increased! If so:

See this Fiddle [working example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/BvvwJ/)

**JQUERY**

```
$('div.start').click(function(){
  var $me = $(this),
      src = 'http://www.laserpros.com/images/site/HP_Circle_Logo_Vector1_small.jpg';

  $('<img style="display:block;display:none;" src="'+src+'">')
    .appendTo($me)
    .css({"display":"block", "opacity":0})
    .animate({opacity:1},2000,function(){
      $('#gotcha').html(1+parseInt($('#gotcha').html()));
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
div.start {
  background-color:#0057D8;
  width:100px;
  float:left;
}
div#gotcha {
  float:left;
  width:100px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
<div class="start">Start</div>
<div id="gotcha">0</div>
```

---

## EDITED

**Edited to what as requested on the comments,** only update #gotcha when the queued animations is empty.

See the new [Fiddle example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/BvvwJ/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="start">Start</div>
<div id="gotcha">0</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
// Jquery Object and image SRC
var $me = $('div.start'),
    src = 'http://www.laserpros.com/images/site/HP_Circle_Logo_Vector1_small.jpg';

// On click over "start"
$me.on("click", function(){
    $('<img style="display:block;display:none;" src="'+src+'">')
        .appendTo($me)                                // append img to div
        .css({"display":"block", "opacity":0})        // hide img
        .animate({opacity:1},2000, function() {       // animate
            if ($me.queue('fx').length==0) {          // if queue is empty
                $('#gotcha').html("1");               // update #gotcha to 1
            }
        });
});
```

**CSS**

```
div.start {
    background-color:#0057D8;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
div#gotcha {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
}
```

Comment: aww, sorry you got it wrong, I admit I wasn't precise with making an example. it was just to demonstrate that we cant queue to parent like that. the number would have to increase only once all the activity had ceased... and it has nothing to do with this

Comment: **ok! No problem.** I just need to better understand your goal. The user clicks "start", the animation is performed and the number gets increased! That part if done on the example that I've posted. But you say _"all the activity had ceased"_! Can you elaborate?

Comment: well, note we can click 10 times, 100 times, and keep clicking more - and they will pop up more. however only once the last one poped up was meant to trigger the callback. my question was actually edited to give some specific details. right now I already made made way to queue the callback to the last loaded child while clearing other older callbacks. But I was still hoping we can make a callback without relying on a queue to a particular child, especially if it'll get bugged for some reason - who knows.

Comment: Still don't follow!! Can you give a practical example of why the number needs to be increased only when the user stops clicking "start", lets say, a million times? :)

Comment: To help you out, a better understanding of the "real life" problem would help us out :)  (By reading your question and that last comment that you've posted here, I'm confused!)

Comment: awww nevermind then bro. the number was just to trace a callback, was never meant to count the images...

Comment: Just edited my answer, the new Fiddle only updates the #gotcha when the queue is empty. While there are animations running, no updates will be made.

Comment: lol mate, but queue simply doesn't work with parent - that was the whole point, and it neither works in your example...

Comment: If I had a hammer ;) The parent isn't being animated, thus it will never work! Sorry bro, no solution here!

Answer (score 0):

Since the time of animation was constant, and it turned out to be just a matter of catching it in a right moment, I decided to go with a general variables, so before I start animation I set the variable to the animation length.

eg.

```
time=400;
```

then I make animation with this timer. 
Later I may add step function for animation to determine the number more precisely...

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, you are trying to run a callback after all animation has completed for a given collection of elements. In this case, a parent element's children:

```
$(parentElement).children().promise().done( function() {
  alert("Animation complete!");
}
```